# Flexslider: data-speed vs slideshowSpeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yii, flexslider

I am trying to adjust the animation time of the Flexslider carousel. I can do this by editing the js "animationSpeed: 600,". However, I would like to edit this setting in html.

An example of this is data-speed="7000" in the html which overides.

var carouselSpeed = carouselInstance.attr("data-speed") ? carouselInstance.attr("data-speed") : "5000"

I've tried animation-speed="600" but this doesn't work. How can I do this?

```
AUTOSTARS.heroflex = function () {      
   $('.heroflex').each(function () {        
     var carouselInstance = $(this);             
var carouselAutoplay = carouselInstance.attr("data-autoplay") == 'yes' ? true : false                 
var carouselSpeed = carouselInstance.attr("data-speed") ? carouselInstance.attr("data-speed") : "5000"                       
carouselInstance.flexslider({           

animation: carouselStyle,                 
easing: "swing",                 
slideshow: carouselAutoplay,                 
slideshowSpeed: carouselSpeed,                 
animationSpeed: 600,                  
});         
});     }



 <div class="hero-slider heroflex flexslider clearfix" data-autoplay="yes" data-pagination="no"
             data-arrows="no" data-style="fade" data-speed="7000">

            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="parallax"
                    style="background-image:url(<?= Yii::$app->params['cygnus-general-assets'] ?>slider-3.jpg);"></li>
                <li class="parallax"
                    style="background-image:url(<?= Yii::$app->params['cygnus-general-assets'] ?>slider-4.jpg);"></li>

            </ul>

    </div>
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

Comment: have you tried to console.log the value retreived? it might be a `string` and need conversion to `integer`?

Comment: try to replace `slideshowSpeed: carouselSpeed, ` by `slideshowSpeed: parseInt(carouselSpeed, 10), ` and tell me if this worked or not

Comment: What you suggested doesn't change the animation speed. I found that altering the number on this line works:

animationSpeed: 3000,

However, I'm trying to figure out how I can do the same thing on the html.

Comment: in your html, `data-speed` is set ot 7000, which seems to be the default speed, did you change that number too? like half, 3500?

Comment: data-speed in html overrides whatever is in the js and that's exactly what I want to be able to do with the animations speed. Override whatever is in the JS by specifying it in the html.